# How do I evaluate this integral $I = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \ln (\sin x +\sqrt{1+\sin^2 x}) dx$?

Tags: integration, logarithms

I used some variables change to evaluate this integral but i'm not succeed  may I have some wrong step as trigono-transformation.Then Is there some one who can show me how do evaluate this : $$I = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \ln (\sin x  +\sqrt{1+\sin^2 x}) dx$$

Thank you for any help .

Comment: Split the integral at $\pi$, and ponder the relationship between $\sqrt{1+\sin^2 x} + \sin x$ and $\sqrt{1 + \sin^2(x+\pi)} + \sin (x+\pi)$.

Comment: i think this integral is zero

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the First : $\sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x} }{2}  \Longrightarrow \sinh^{-1}x = \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}).$

to get this just solve the equation $y=\sinh x$ to get the above inverse function (notice that $e^x>0$). The integral becomes :

\begin{align*} \int_0^{2\pi} \sinh^{-1} \sin x\ \mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^{\pi} \sinh ^{-1} \sin x \ \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \sinh^{-1} \sin x \ \mathrm{d}x \\ &=  \int_0^{\pi} \sinh ^{-1} \sin x \ \mathrm{d}x+  \int_0^{\pi} \sinh ^{-1} \sin (x+\pi) \ \mathrm{d}x \\ &=  \int_0^{\pi} \sinh ^{-1} \sin x \ \mathrm{d}x -  \int_0^{\pi} \sinh ^{-1} \sin x \ \mathrm{d}x  \\ &=0.\end{align*}

(the $\sinh^{-1}$ function is odd)

Comment: thank you for this good answer , it's a nice variable change

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way of evaluating the integral.  Let $f(x)$ be an odd function with period $2\pi$.  Then, we will show that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\log \left(f(x)+\sqrt{f^2(x)+1}\right)dx=0$$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(f(x) +\sqrt{1+f^2(x)}\right)dx&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log\left(f(x) +\sqrt{1+f^2(x)}\right)dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{0}\log\left(f(x) +\sqrt{1+f^2(x)}\right)dx\\
&+\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\left(f(x) +\sqrt{1+f^2(x)}\right)dx\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\left(-f(x) +\sqrt{1+f^2(x)}\right)dx\\
&+\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\left(f(x) +\sqrt{1+f^2(x)}\right)dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\left(\log(-f(x) +\sqrt{1+f^2(x)}\right)+\log\left(f(x) +\sqrt{1+f^2(x)})\right)dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\log (1) dx\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\sin x$ is odd with period $2\pi$, we immediately have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^{2\pi}\log \left(\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2 x+1}\right)dx=0}$$